# how to download images from scrapy python and save them to a folder and their path in the variable

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, scrapy, scrapy-item

```
import scrapy
import json


class Brand(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
    brand_image = scrapy.Field()
    productsList = scrapy.Field()


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "brandDetails"
    def start_requests(self):
        with open('brands.json') as data_file:
            data_item = json.load(data_file)
        urls = list()
        for item in data_item:
            urls.append(item["url"])
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        item = Brand()
        name = response.css("div.th::text").extract_first()
        name = name.replace('Products of ', '')
        item['name'] = name
        item['url'] = response.url
```

I want to download an image and url to look like this `"/get.aspx?id=1988147"`
and save the downloaded image to a file, with the save path in the item like `item['image']`.

```
        image = response.css("div.productimage img::attr(src)").extract_first()
        # example of src of image = > /get.aspx?id=1988147
        yield item
```

Answer (score -2):

Scrapy has a built-in mechanism for downloading files, [media pipelines](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html).

In the simplest case, you would set a field of your item (either `file_urls` or `image_urls`), activate the pipeline in your `settings.py`, and set the path (`FILES_STORE` or `IMAGES_STORE`) you want to download to.
If you need to make additional changes, you can create a custom subclass.

This is enough to download the files you want, as well as save some additional metadata.

Comment: 'def parse(self, response):
 item = Brand() 
name = response.css("div.th::text").extract_first() name = name.replace('Products of ', '') 
item['name'] = name 
item['url'] = response.url url = response.css("div.productimage img::attr(src)").extract_first() 
url = "ozhat-turkiye.com"; + url 
item['image_urls'] = url yield item'

yield item

Comment: Code in comments is unreadable. Also, do you have a question about that code?